# EXTJS ReRendering of the Grid with Datastore

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a grid made with ExtJS, and I render it to a div that I define, when a refresh is requested I simply "empty" the div using JQuery and then re-render the grid creating new objects each time:

```
    var grid = new xg.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
    ...
    renderTo: 'db-grid'
```

And then to empty the div I use this:

```
    $("#db-grid").empty();
```

This works well for like 3 or 4 refreshes, and then it seems to load really slowly, I imagine this is because it re-creates all these objects again, the only thing that changes each time is the "store." I acquire that through an AJAX request, is there a way to refresh this without creating a new grid each time?

I'm pretty new to ExtJS, and I'm making a bit of a transition here from JQuery, which is why I'm using the "empty()" function from JQuery, if you know of a ExtJS alternative, I would be glad to use that instead,

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Store's `load(Object options)` and `reload(Object options)` methods at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/.

An example of this functionality can be seen in `Ext.PagingToolbar`. This class contains a button that refreshes a Grid and its Store, without destroying the Grid each time:

```
    // private
    doLoad : function(start){
        var o = {}, pn = this.getParams();
        o[pn.start] = start;
        o[pn.limit] = this.pageSize;
        if(this.fireEvent('beforechange', this, o) !== false){
            this.store.load({params:o}); // here is the call you're interested in
        }
    },
```

`doLoad()` is then simply called from the method `doRefresh()`:

```
    doRefresh : function(){
        this.doLoad(this.cursor);
    },
```

I included this code for the sake of a complete example, but really all you need to worry about is the load() or reload() methods. Make sure to read the API to see a full list of arguments that can be passed into the methods.